# Vanilla JavaScript list item not showing one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

```js
function intervalTextChange() {
  var listElements = document.querySelectorAll("#uspList");
  var index = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (index < listElements[0].children.length - 1) {
      index++;
    } else {
      index = 0;
    }
    listElements[0].children[index].classList.add("active-usp");
    listElements[0].children[index].classList.remove("active-usp");
  }, 1200);
};

intervalTextChange();
```

```css
.list__item {
    display: none;
    color: lightgreen;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.94s ease-in-out;
}

.active-usp {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    animation: animateEntryElement 0.94s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes animateEntryElement {
    from {display: none; opacity: 0}
    to {display: block; opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<ul id="uspList" class="list list__basic-vertical">
  <li class="list__item" data-order="0">1</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="1">2</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="2">3</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="3">4</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="4">5</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to show each list element for 2 seconds then hide it. After that, the next list item will behave the same as the first one.

This is the link with the code: https://jsbin.com/baxobuwoli/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Please show the relevant code here in the post itself, and describe also your problem in details.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I only want to show 1 list item at a time, and then hide it after 2 seconds. After that, the next element in the list will do the same (show and hide), until it reaches the last element and returns back to the first one with the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but what is the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `document.querySelectorAll("#uspList");` is pointless. There only ever can be a single element with ID `uspList` in your document anyway.

Either get that single element:

```
var list = document.querySelector("#uspList");
```

or use an expression that can actually returns more than one result:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#uspList > li");
```

Since you're intending to change the `<li>` elements, let's go with the latter:

```js
function intervalTextChange() {
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#uspList > li"),
    i = 0;
  
  listItems[i].classList.add("active-usp");
  
  setInterval(function () {
    listItems[i].classList.remove("active-usp");
    i = (i + 1) % listItems.length;
    listItems[i].classList.add("active-usp");
  }, 1200);
};

intervalTextChange();
```

```css
.list__item {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.94s ease-in-out;
}

.active-usp {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    animation: animateEntryElement 0.94s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes animateEntryElement {
    from {display: none; opacity: 0}
    to {display: block; opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<ul id="uspList" class="list list__basic-vertical">
  <li class="list__item" data-order="0">Item 1</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="1">Item 2</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="2">Item 3</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="3">Item 4</li>
  <li class="list__item" data-order="4">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for your problem is by using the function `setInterval`. In the beginning you have to get your list by
`const list = document.querySelectorAll('li')`. The next step is to set `display: none` to every element of your list. The easiest way is by adding class, but I made function called `handleVisibility` which sets every li on `display: none`. The last step is to make a loop which will increment on every interval. In cleanup function you can choose that you won't the loop repeat or none by setting the value of `i = 0` or `clearInterval(counter)`

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('li')

const handleVisibility = () => {
  list.forEach(li => {
    li.classList.add('visibility')
  })
}

const handleChange = () => {
  handleVisibility()
  let i = 0;
  let counter = setInterval(() => {
    handleVisibility()
    list[i].classList.remove('visibility')
    i++
    if (i === list.length) {
      i = 0
    }
  }, 2000)
}
handleChange()
```

```css
.visibility {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask :)